# How to change Grid.RowDefinitions depending on Orientation

Tags: c#, xamarin

So I wanted to change size of my scrollview depending on orientation.

My initial code is:

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" x:Name="RowDefModifier" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="2,2,2,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="webPanel" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" >
                    <WebView x:Name="webView"></WebView>
                </ScrollView>
...
```

And I am changing height of RowDefModifier like this:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            if (width > height)
            {
                RowDefModifier.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
            }
            else
            {
                RowDefModifier.Height = new GridLength(2.0, GridUnitType.Star);
            }
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        }
```

Problem is that when Height is first time set as "2*", setting it back to "1*" doesn't work anymore.

For example if first time Height is set to "1*", and then I change orientation to vertical (2*), if I go back to horizontal it will not change.

Comment: Does the function fire when you change the screen orientation?

Comment: Height is a bindable property, try modifying the value via the ViewModel maybe.

Comment: Slipoch, jest it does. I think that problem is that when it will go bigger, then it's not going to shrink :(

Comment: i refer to https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/ResponsiveLayout/ResponsiveLayout/GridPageXaml.xaml.cs,and works for me

Comment: NOTE: The code shown will not change the size of anything. `2*` is only meaningful if there are other `*`-based rows. If there is only one `*`-based row, then it will use all remaining space, regardless of the "multiplier".